# Создание скрипта для вывода данных из баз MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно создать скрипт для вывода данных из баз MySQL на языке PHP. 
Подскажите новичку, как к этому подступиться, на что обратить внимание?

Comment: начать изучать пхп...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

простой пример

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','database');
$query = 'select * from tableName';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "ID - ".$item['row1']."<br>";
    echo "Note: ".$item['row2']."<br>";
    echo "date: ".$item['row2']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: @Elikor, если бы вы показали скрин таблицы (в своем вопросе) из того же pma, ответ был бы точней!

Comment: Вы правы, добавил.

Comment: @Elikor в вашем случае, нужно заменить `$item['row1']` на `$item['id']` чтобы получить значение столбца id из вашей таблицы

Comment: @StereoFlo  а  MYSQLI_ASSOC это что?

Comment: @Elikor константа, которая отвечает за формирование ассоциативного массива, в момент выдачи результатов в БД.