# Ошибка при выполнении sql-запроса PHP

Tags: php

При исполнении *sql-запроса* выдаёт ошибку.

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table_products $cat WHERE table_products", $link);
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($count);
$post = $temp[0];
```

Comment: Да, даже в заголовке инфинитив вместо третьего лица.

Comment: и эта ошибка вам не о чем не говорит ? у вас запрос совершенно не верно составлен

Comment: я сделал из интернет магазин  сделал

Comment: функции mysql_* являются устаревшими, используйте mysqli_ [пример тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835541/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7-mysql/835543#835543)